# Outside of Sabotage, how could a Rogue damage items?

Tags: damage, rogue, objects, pathfinder-2e

While reading through the class feats in Pathfinder 2e I came across this one for Rogue: [Sabotage](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=565).  It allows a rogue to deal damage to a carried or wielded item with moving parts (such as a shortbow) based on a skill check vs Reflex, but explicitly states that said damage cannot take the item below it's Broken Threshold which is the point before damage has any mechanical effect.

This implies to me the existence of at least one other method to deal at least one point of damage to a wielded or carried item to keep this feat from being functionally useless, but as of yet I've been unable to find any method to do so.  One section on [Items and Hit Points](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=386) even outright says:

> You usually can’t attack an attended object (one on a creature’s person)

So direct attacking is out, but there are definitely exceptions such as the aforementioned Sabotage.

That leads to my question, **what other methods to damage held/wielded items are there?**  And more specifically, what others options are there that are available to a Rogue?

For what it's worth while I don't consider Spells as an option "available" to Rogue, if those are the only options that would be good to know as well, especially if such could include what steps a Rogue would have to take to gain access to them realistically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Despite what the question is asking, [Sabotage](https://pf2.d20pfsrd.com/class/rogue/#Sabotage_one-action_Feat_4) actually says, in part

> Damage dealt by Sabotage can’t take the item below its Break Threshold.

And the rules on [Item Hit Points](https://pf2.d20pfsrd.com/rules/playing-the-game/#Items_and_Hit_Points) say

> Items have Hit Points like creatures, but the rules for damaging them are different. An item has a Hardness statistic that reduces damage the item takes by that amount. The item then takes any damage left over. If an item is reduced to 0 HP, it’s destroyed. An item also has a Broken Threshold. **If its HP are reduced to this amount or lower**, it’s broken, meaning it can’t be used for its normal function and it doesn’t grant bonuses.

So, Sabotage **can** make an object be Broken, but cannot damage it any further than that.

As for other methods of purposely damaging object, the only other example I could think of in the Core rulebook was using the Shield Block reaction, which causes damage to be done to the shield used. And a rogue couldn't really force anyone to take that reaction.

In addition, a number of creatures in the Bestiary have effects that can cause damage to objects. For example, a [Black Pudding](https://pf2.d20pfsrd.com/monster/black-pudding/) has the Corrosive Touch ability, which will cause damage to clothing and armour. The [Rust Monster](https://pf2.d20pfsrd.com/monster/rust-monster/) can also corrode metal items held by an enemy.